# Can I access redux props/application state inside of Component State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So let's say that I've added clothing pieces to a back-end rails api and Im trying to access these items through the React side of things, I know I can use the mapStateToProps(state){} function. However, I want to create interactivity in the UI between different pieces of application state from reducers (or redux store) where interactivity between different pieces of state are dependent on current state in component constructors. Is it possible for me to access this.props.contemplatedPiece for example in the constructor? Babel tells me Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.props.getInitialPieces();
        this.state = {
            if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type == 'top'){
                currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0],
                currentUpperComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
                LowerComponents, UpperComponents: this.props.organizePieces();
            }
            else if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type == 'bottom'){
                currentLowerComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
                currentUpperComponent: this.props.suggestedTops[0],
                UpperComponents, LowerComponents: this.props.organizePieces();
            }
            currentComponent: {whichComponent: null, whichPiece: null}
            UpperComponentEnabled: false,
            LowerComponentEnabled: false
        };
};


isOppositeComponentSuggested(whichComponent){
        var match = false;
        _.debounce((whichComponent) => {
            this.props.setContemplatedPiece(whichComponent).then(function(){
                this.props.getAncillaryPieces();
                if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type == 'top'){
                    this.props.suggestedBottoms.map((bottom) => {
                        if (this.state.currentLowerComponent == bottom){
                                match = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type == 'bottom'){
                    this.props.suggestedTops.map((top) => {
                        if (this.state.currentUpperComponent == top){
                            match = true;
                        }               
                    });
                }
            });
        }, 6000);

        return match;
    }

    switchFocus(){
        if (this.state.currentUpperComponent.hasFocus()){
            this.state.currentLowerComponent.focus();
        }
        else if(this.state.currentLowerComponent.hasFocus()){       
            this.state.currentUpperComponent.focus();   
        }
        else {
          break;
        }
    }

    render(){
         return(
               <Wardrobe upperComponent={this.state.currentUpperComponent} lowerComponent={this.state.currentLowerComponent} currentComponent = {this.state.currentComponent} enableCapture={snapshot => this.snapshotMatch = snapshot} />
               <div className = "PossibleMatches_Container">
                    <i class = 'captureOutfit' onClick = {this.snapshotMatch}></i> 
                    {this.state.fieldForOrganizedPiecesArray.UpperComponents.map(function(topPiece){  
                        <UpperComponent key={topPiece.id} id={topPiece.id} ref={(piece)=>{this.setState({currentUpperComponent: piece})}} setCurrentComponent = {(piece) => this.setState(currentComponent.whichPiece: piece, currentComponent.whichComponent: 'u', lowerComponent: null, upperComponent: null)}  toggleToPiece={this.setState({currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0]}).then(function(){if (this.state.LowerComponentEnabled: false){this.setState(LowerComponentEnabled: true)}else{break;}})} image={topPiece.image} isLowerComponentEnabled={this.state.LowerComponentEnabled} switchComponent={this.switchFocus} evaluatePiece={isOppositeComponentSuggested} className={if (this.state.currentComponent.whichComponent == 'l'){'standalonePiece'}else if(this.state.currentComponent.whichComponent == 'l'){'PossibleMatchCollapse'} else{'UpperComponent_Container'}}/>
                    });}
                    {this.state.fieldForOrganizedPiecesArray.LowerComponents.map(function(bottomPiece){
                        <LowerComponent key={bottomPiece.id} id={bottomPiece.id} ref={(piece)=>{this.setState({currentLowerComponent: piece})}} setCurrentComponent = {(piece) => this.setState(currentComponent.whichPiece: piece, currentComponent.whichComponent: 'l', upperComponent: null, lowerComponent: null);}  toggleToPiece={this.setState({currentUpperComponent: this.props.suggestedTops[0]}).then(function(){if(this.state.UpperComponentEnabled: false){this.setState(UpperComponentEnabled: true)}})} isUpperComponentEnabled={this.state.UpperComponentEnabled} switchComponent={this.switchFocus} evaluatePiece={isOppositeComponentSuggested} className={ if (this.state.currentComponent.whichComponent == 'l'){'standalonePiece'} else if(this.state.currentComponent.whichComponent == 'u'){'PossibleMatchCollapse'} else{'LowerComponent_Container'}}/>
                    });}
                </div>
         );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        contemplatedPiece: state.possibleMatches.contemplated_piece,
        extraTops: state.possibleMatches.extraTops,
        extraBottoms: state.possibleMatches.extraBottoms,
        standaloneTops: state.possibleMatches.standaloneTops,
        standaloneBottoms: state.possibleMatches.standaloneBottoms,
        suggestedTops: state.possibleMatches.suggestedTops,
        suggestedBottoms: state.possibleMatches.suggestedBottoms,
        UpperComponents: state.possibleMatches.UpperComponents,
        LowerComponents: state.possibleMatches.LowerComponents
    };
}
```

Here is the rest of the code

Comment: you have some javascript issues preventing the interpreter to parse/transpile your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to point some javascript invalid expressions in your code:

```
constructor(){
    // To properly access to `this.props` in the Component constructor you must call the `super`
    this.props.getInitialPieces();
    this.state = {
        // next lines is invalid on object initialization
        // use instead the ternary operator `?:`
        if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type == 'top'){ // <-- error: invalid syntax (if statement is invalid here)
           currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0],
           currentUpperComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
           LowerComponents, UpperComponents: this.props.organizePieces();
        }
}
```

Probably you need to go with this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); // constructor receive `props`, need to call `super`
        props.getInitialPieces();
        const condition = props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type == 'top';
        this.state = {
           currentLowerComponent: condition ? this.props.suggestedBottoms[0] : undefined,
           // same logic with conditional props
        };
    }
}
```

---

> SyntaxError: this is a reserved word

The new error occurs because on object declarations you must indicate `propName: value`:

```
{ 
    propsA: valueA,
    propB: this.props.organizePieces().map(function(results){})
}
```

Here is some revisions / fixes over the updated code, but I recommend you to read the javascript language specs and do some tutorials to get used to it.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.getInitialPieces();

        // this change is related of using an inline map function inline in the object, with no target property to assign the result.
        // E.g. Correct syntax { prop: this.props.organizePieces().map() }
        const organizedPiecesArray = this.props.organizePieces().map(function(results) {
            // need to `return` an Object:
            return {
                UpperComponents: results.PossibleMatches.UpperComponents,
                LowerComponents: results.PossibleMatches.LowerComponents
            };
        });

        const initialState = {
            // define property to hold the mapped `organizedPiecesArray`
            fieldForOrganizedPiecesArray: organizedPiecesArray,
            currentComponent: { whichComponent: null, whichPiece: null },
            UpperComponentEnabled: false,
            LowerComponentEnabled: false
        };

        if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type === 'top') {
            this.state = {
                ...initialState, // spread `initialState` to copy their properties
                currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0],
                currentUpperComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
            };
        } else if (this.props.contemplatedPiece.merch_type === 'bottom') {
            this.state = {
                ...initialState,
                currentLowerComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
                currentUpperComponent: this.props.suggestedTops[0],
            };
        } else {
            // if it's possible a third alternative, what's the initial state here?
        }
    }
}
```

Related resources:

- Check your javascript code [here](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html)
- Read more about the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- Check [React Component constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) docs
- [JavaScript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)

Comment: One thing isn't clear about your `mapStateToProps` function is where it's declared. Probably you need to check the [Redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md). Also, consider to select an answer to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I added the rest of the code to clarify any misunderstanding.

Comment: I see you have more syntax and semantic issues in your code. Need more help with those errors?

Comment: So at the part where I indicated error is the part of the code that is giving me a new problem. Thanks in advance. You've been most helpful.

Comment: Please, If your initial question is solved consider to mark/accept this answer to spot your original question is done. Also consider to create another question with new concerns and if you want me to take a look at let me know the link in a follow comment. Thanks

Comment: I think you should accept the right (or more suitable) answer for your question

Comment: I figured out how to mark this question as solved. This is the link that you were referring to in the comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269564/babel-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-expected. I would appreciate it if you could take a look and see what's causing the error. Thanks.

Comment: I checked your new question, and let you some hints and references to read. Also consider to re-update this page question to match the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Your React component class receives `props` in its constructor:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // First pass the props to super (base class constructor)
        super(props);

        // Now create your state with the props
        this.state = {
            myVar = props.var
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have an `if` block inside of an object literal. That is not valid javascript. You can only have key/value pairs inside an object literal:

```js
this.state = {
    // this is an object
    // no 'if' allowed here
    // key: value
    myKey: myValue,
};
```

Also the `mapStateToProps` function should not be a member of your component instance. It it a function that takes the current redux state as a parameter and returns the props that should be passed to the component. You have to use it together with the redux `connect()` function:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    myProp: state.aProp,
});

const MyConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

It seems to me you should start with the redux tutorial first.

Also the constructor of a react component has to call it's `super` constructor with the `props` it gets or your component will break:

```js
constructor(props){
    // you must call super here
    super(props);

    // additional initialization here
}
```

Of course you can use the `props` passed to the constructor to initialize your state properly.

Answer (score 0):

you syntax error this is a reserved words, could be related to:

```
this.state = {
    currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0],
    currentUpperComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
    this.props.organizePieces().map(function(results){ <-- Error
        UpperComponents: results.PossibleMatches.UpperComponents;
        LowerComponents: results.PossibleMatches.LowerComponents;
    });
    currentComponent: {whichComponent: null, whichPiece: null}
    UpperComponentEnabled: false,
    LowerComponentEnabled: false
}
```

this.state = {} is an Object Literal, you can assign values to properties, within this Object.

On the 3th line within this.state, you are trying to assign the result of the map function, (which would return an array, (well actually it would return nothing, because you don't return anything)) to, well actually nothing :D, you just call it. so it breaks after the first dot, then it just tries to assign "this" with nothing but this is reserved. (i would have expected a different error, something like unexpected token though, but it could be babel is not transforming correctly, because of this error) and this error is given.

```
this.state = {
    currentLowerComponent: this.props.suggestedBottoms[0],
    currentUpperComponent: this.props.contemplatedPiece,
    whatever: this.props.organizePieces().map(results => ({ 
        UpperComponents: results.PossibleMatches.UpperComponents,
        LowerComponents: results.PossibleMatches.LowerComponents,
    })), <-- No Error
    currentComponent: {whichComponent: null, whichPiece: null},
    UpperComponentEnabled: false,
    LowerComponentEnabled: false
}
```

- no error: assuming organizePieces() <-- is a function that returns a array.
- you can also not use ; within a object literal
- don't forget the ,  at the end of each value
- you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.